# freeStyleJob Jenkins DSL job runs complicated bash script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, syntax-error, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to run a complicated bash script from my Jenkins job:

```
steps {
    shell(readFileFromWorkspace('./complicated_script.sh'))
}
```

The call works great, the problem is that when I'm running the seed job, the job fails because of the wrong syntax of the Bash script.

The script is written good and it's much more complicated than "echo" commands.

Writing the script down between shell() command works fine but it's a too big script to keep it there - it needs its own file.

I tried to work with [groovy syntax](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgroovy-lang.org%2Fsyntax.html%23all-strings&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGmXXolsJ2PN9TjhQKB3vTNeZ-XLw) to escape all the special characters and it's still not working, same error messages: unexpected char, expected EOF but instead...

Looking around to find examples of complicated bash script from Jenkins Job DSL and I haven't found.

Part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
set -e

SERVER="hostname.example.com"
TLS_SSL_ARRAY=(tlsv1.0 tlsv1.1 tlsv1.2 sslv2 sslv3)
url="https://${SERVER}/api/test"
RESULT_FILE="output_file.txt"

for version in ${TLS_SSL_ARRAY[*]}
do
    check_url=$(curl --${version} ${url})
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "${version}- Enabled" >> $RESULT_FILE 
else
    echo "${version} - Disabled" >> $RESULT_FILE 
fi

done

sudo -u ${username} scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $RESULT_FILE hostname2.example.com:/tmp/
```

How can I "convert" this bash script to bash-readable-by-Jenkins? As I wrote before I tried a lot of combinations as written in the groovy-lang syntax web.

Comment: Try verifying your shell script via https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks! Yes I did and it's working okay and even the script running okay when I'm using "shell('''SCRIPT SYNTAX''')". The problem is when I'm calling to a script file, it's just not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
steps {
  script {
    sh "${WORKSPACE}/complicated_script.sh"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is DSL, not pipeline - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so posting the Answer here in case someone would experience this as well:
the problem was the configuration in the DSL plugin at the seed Job - Mistakely I configured the plugin to read all the files at the folder, instead of reading only the `*.groovy` files.